# "More produced than requested" exception when using `replay` and `autoConnect`

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I want to create an observable that emits values from underlying hot observable (starting with `-1` before that), only when new value is different than the previous one. Additionally I want latest value to be immediately emitted to new subscribers. I've come up with following code:

```
PublishSubject<Integer> hotObservable = PublishSubject.create();

Observable<Integer> observable = hotObservable
        .startWith(-1)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .replay(1)
        .autoConnect(0);
```

However this fails after first value (always `-1`, regardless of what `hotObservable` emits before subscribing to `observable`) emitted to new subscriber with `java.lang.IllegalStateException: more produced than requested`
 Interestingly, when I don't automatically connect, but manually subscribe:

```
Observable<Integer> observable = hotObservable
        .startWith(-1)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .replay(1)
        .autoConnect();

observable.subscribe().unsubscribe();
```

following subscribers work properly, receiving last value and then updates.

I can't get `replay(1).autoConnect(0)` to work, and I feel like I miss something - why would subscribing and unsubscribing work, while `autoConnect(0)` wouldn't? What's the proper way to create such observable?

Here's test method that fails unless I use `autoConnect(); observable.subscribe().unsubscribe()`:

```
Observable<Integer> observable = hotObservable
        .startWith(-1)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .replay(1)
        .autoConnect(); // With (0) it fails

observable.subscribe().unsubscribe(); // Needed if we don't auto connnect

hotObservable.onNext(1);
hotObservable.onNext(2);
hotObservable.onNext(3); // I want this value to be received by new subscriber

TestSubscriber<Integer> subscriber = TestSubscriber.create();
observable.subscribe(subscriber);

subscriber.assertNoErrors();
subscriber.assertValues(3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get the `More produced than requested` error with the code above on RxJava 1.1.3.

The reason the assertion fails is that `replay` won't request anything from upstream until any of its Subscribers actually request. If the `TestSubscriber` is the first to subscribe, it will trigger the startWith to emit -1 and then switch to the PublishSubject which doesn't retain any value thus you don't receive anything else.

I believe what you are looking for is `BehaviorSubject` which keeps the very last value and starts with that for new subscribers:

```
BehaviorSubject<Integer> hotObservable = BehaviorSubject.create(-1);

Observable<Integer> observable = hotObservable.distinctUntilChanged();

hotObservable.onNext(1);
hotObservable.onNext(2);
hotObservable.onNext(3);

TestSubscriber<Integer> subscriber = TestSubscriber.create();
observable.subscribe(subscriber);

subscriber.assertNoErrors();
subscriber.assertValue(3);
```

Comment: Can confirm version `1.1.3` works! I was on `1.1.2` before. As for `BehaviorSubject` - this is interesting, however `hotObservable` is in fact created elsewhere. Is `BehaviorSubject b = BehaviorSubject.create(-1); hotObservable.subscribe(b); return b.distinctUntilChanged()` valid approach as well?

Comment: Yes it is a valid approach. You may want to add `onBackpressureBuffer` or `onBackpressureDrop` in case the hotObservable signals values too fast.

Comment: I've added `onBackpressureLatest()`. Thanks a lot for your help!